# Does any DRM system work within a Virtual Machine?

Tags: cryptography, hardware, virtualization, tpm, drm

I'm running a few quick tests to see if any DRM system works on a VM.  Notably, most DRM systems (haven't found one yet), don't work on a virtual device:

- iPhone Simulator on OSX (FairPlay)
- Windows Phone Simulator
- Android Simulator
- Virtual machine on Mac/Pc base hardware (Parallels, Virtual Box, VMWare?)

Is there any combination of base hardware (Mac/PC), base OS, and Virtualized OS that allows a given DRM system to work?

My testing of FairPlay, PlayFair, Widevine/Chrome [on this website](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/samples.html) resulted in no success unless on the actual base OS.

Comment: what type of DRM?

Comment: @schroeder updated: FairPlay, PlayFair, Widevine ... and whatever Firefox uses (Adobe I think)

Comment: You might get some to work if you use PCI passthrough to hand over the GPU to the VM. Perhaps hiding the superviser is also necessary.

Comment: @CodesInChaos my real (eventual) goal is to understand which if any leverage hardware protections such as a secure element, or TPM.  I'd be slightly less enthused about DRM solutions that stored private keys in the OS, readable with a hex editor (or similar)

Comment: @schroeder DRM is a system by which developers spend months trying to prevent people from pirating there code ... which is usually bypassed with in a week or so of the software being released ... see also: `fool's errand`